# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: magento-1.4

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error when trying to update a product, I keep going round in circles & not getting anywhere.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'

We are on an old version 1.4 which is being updated in new year but need to fix this asap!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but on `catalogrule_product_price`.

i changed a value for the auto_increment ID of that table from int(10) to bigint(10) in database.

so 4294967295 is not your last ID and it will work for while more ;)

for your problem it should be the `catalog_product_entity` field `entity_id` change type to `BIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to tell you much as we do not know which table this is occurring at. Search the database for that ID (4294967295) and see if you can find where it's trying to create this entry. Since the ID is very big I am assuming that it's an error of some sort (unless you have 4 billion products in your store). It may be as easy as deleting that entry, back your things up before you removes stuff though. 
I assume you will find that erroring entry in the `catalog_product_entity` table.

What I would do is xdebug the saving process on a local environment and trace the saving attempt to see what values it's trying to pass. So if you have that setup going for you, you should start there.